# Query that recursively compare a record with the previous one

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have the following table sample

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Transactions](
    [TransactionID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TransactionTypeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Counter] [int] NOT NULL,
    [GivenCounter] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ExecutionDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Transactions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TransactionID] ASC)
```

The `TransactionTypeID` field identify the type of transaction:

- 1 means Activation
- 2 means Consumption
- 3 means Cancellation

In particular the `type 3` refers to the cancellation of the previous transaction. So if the transaction which has been executed prior to cancellation (in terms of ExecutionDate) is a `type 2` means the cancellation of a consumption while if the previous transaction is a `type 1` means that the cancellation is a de-activation.

How can I query only for transactions which the meanings is deactivation (`type 3` with previous `type 1`)?
Can anyone help please?

EDIT: Added some sample data to better explain

```
TransactionID   TransactionTypeID   Counter  GivenCounter    ExecutionDate  
--------------  -----------------   -------  ------------    -----------------------
138327              1               1          0             2014-07-20 07:14:08.000
134175              2               0          1             2014-07-21 12:39:12.000
137620              3               1          1             2014-07-22 20:19:06.000
134199              1               1          0             2014-07-23 10:09:52.000
132772              3               0          1             2014-07-24 08:18:23.000
```

In this example my query should extract only one record (`TransactionID` 132772) because it is a cancellation of the previous transaction that had `TransactionTypeID` equals to 1

Comment: How do you know that `132772` is a cancellation of `131199`? Surely there must be some column that ties those two together?

Comment: No. There is'nt any column that ties together the records. Records with `TransactionTypeID = 3` ties with the immediately previous record in term of execution date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
SELECT a.transactionid 
FROM   (SELECT *, Row_number() OVER(ORDER BY ExecutionDate) AS Rownumber 
        FROM   transactions) a 
       JOIN (SELECT transactiontypeid, Row_number()  OVER( ORDER BY ExecutionDate) AS Rownumber 
             FROM   transactions) b 
         ON a.rownumber = b.rownumber + 1 
WHERE  a.transactiontypeid = 1 
       AND b.transactiontypeid = 3
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I dont think that using `Row_number()` would satisfy my requirement. The only thing that is sure is the usage of the `ExecutionDate` field by selecting the first available transaction which has `ExecutionDate less than current ExecutionDate`

Comment: I think it will work if you order the table by ExecutionDate, See my edit

Comment: Ok. Let me do some tests and I'll be back to you shortly

Comment: This is working perfectly. I have only inverted the where you have because the first must be type 1 and the second type 3. I have also edited your answer. Great. Many thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I've updated my answer, can you please try this ?

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT 
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY (TransactionTypeID) ORDER BY (ExecutionDate)) AS 'RowNo',
TransactionID, TransactionTypeID, ExecutionDate
FROM dbo.Transactions2
WHERE TransactionTypeID = 3
 ) AS A
WHERE RowNo = 2;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately I cannot use `Counter` and `GivenCounter` to select data. There are more values that those in the sample data. I just need to use `TransactionTypeID` and `ExecutionDate`

Comment: this will output the correct row for the testdata above, but it's just a coincidence

Comment: Hey Lorenzo, are you sure TheJoe's answer is working fine? I have tested it on sample data and I'm also getting the transactionid of the Cancellations that also have an activation and a consumption !!! please double check.

Comment: @Claudio: Yes Claudio. I have a database with over 130K records and I know the results I have to expect. I have tested that query against different conditions and it seems to work perfectly to me. Which is your doubt?

Comment: This line of TheJoelaut's code should be like this ON a.rownumber = b.rownumber - 1  instead of +1... I tested it on sample data. The +1 also returns some transactionid's that contain the idtype 1,2,3 and not just the ones with 1,3